# How Download File in php for Big Size

Tags: php, file, curl, download, mp4

I should download Big file video with size 200mb in local pc drive.

The code is correct for medium size but fail with big size with return ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE.

I have tried also with readfile and file_get_contents method without succesfull.

My code php is:

```
<?php
Header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=a.mp4");
Header("Content-Description: Download Manager");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
Header("Pragma: No-Cache");
Header("Expires: 0");
ob_clean();
$path="http://myurlexample/...../a.mp4"
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if(curl_exec($ch) === FALSE) {
         echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
         echo curl_exec($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
flush();
exit();
?>
```

Comment: You do realise that if the `curl_exec()`  is successful, you then run it again? Surely not intended??

Comment: Why not `$result = curl_exec($ch); if($result === FALSE) {echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch);} curl_close(); echo $result;...`

Comment: What's the point of `ob_clean();`- which output do you want to erase from the buffer at that point?

Comment: It might be useful to turn on the curl verbose logging (see https://everything.curl.dev/libcurl/verbose ) and check out what is actually communicated by the server as the invalid response. Feel free to add relevant parts of the verbose transcript to the question.